# If $X$ is any convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ,then show that $\pi_1(X,x_0)=0$

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

If $X$ is any convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ,then show that  $\pi_1(X,x_0)=0$

My attempt : By using the theorem any convex subspace  $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is contractible

There is  a  continuous map $F : X \times [0,1] \to X$ such that $F(\cdot,0) = f$ and $F(\cdot,1) = c$.

This implies $[f] =[c] $

since $[f] \in \pi_1(X,x_0) \implies [c] \in  \pi_1(X,x_0) $

Therefore  $ \pi_1(X,x_0) =[c]=0$

Is my proof is correct or not ?

Comment: Any subspace? Maybe you mean convex subset?

Comment: $X$ convex does not mean that $X$ is a subspace.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I edited yes convex subset

Comment: This seems ok to me.

Comment: You can explicitly give a homotopy.

Comment: okk @copper.hat  you mean  i have to write this  $F(t, s) = sx_0 + (1 − s)f(t).?$

Comment: You don't have to, contractible is adequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Fix $x_0\in X$ and let $I=[0,1]$.  Let
$$
F:I\times X\rightarrow X
$$
be defined by $F(s,x)=(1-s)x+sx_0$ (we can do this because $X$ is convex).  Then $F(0,\cdot )=id_X$ and $F(1,\cdot)=x_0$.  What we've shown so far is that a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a contractible space.

Now let $c: I\rightarrow X$ be a (continuous) curve such that $c(0)=c(1)=x_0$.  Let $G:I\times I\rightarrow X$ be defined by
$$
G(t,s):=F(s,c(t)).
$$
Then $G(t,0)=c(t)$ and $G(t,1)=x_0$.  Hence, $c(t)$ is homotopic to the constant curve.  Since $c(t)$ was arbitrary, we have $\pi_1(X,x_0)=\{[x_0]\}$, i.e., its trivial.

In proving that $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is trivial, we only made use of the fact that $X$ is contractible.  Hence, we actually proved something more general: if $Y$ is any contractible space, then $\pi_1(Y,y_0)$ is trivial.